# Why does DNS addressability between namespaces depend on pod definition type?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I'm running into a challenge with creating a mongo replica set that spans two namespaces in a single cluster.  I thought I had things worked out but now I'm confused about how `NodePort` services interact with pods.

I had initially been able to get the replica set working using fairly simple mongo pod definition (i.e., kind: `Pod`) and `NodePort` service definition (I will ultimately need external visibility.)  Here's the `NodePort` definition for ns0:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    name: mongo
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: mongo
    port: 30000
    targetPort: 30000
    nodePort: 30000
```

This configuration created DNS names like `mongo.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local` that can be addressed from both pods in `ns0` and in `ns1`.

Later, when attempting to apply some changes to a previously deployed set of pods, I learned that there are certain things you cannot update for a pod.  I think that helped me understand why pods are not typically used in production, and I modified the yaml to use a `kind: StatefulSet` instead of `kind: Pod`.  (Sorry for the awkward language here, I'm trying to avoid the term 'deployment' since it means something specific in k8s.)

This resulted in a new DNS name for the pod: `mongo-0.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local` which is reachable within `ns0`.  However, that name is not addressable from `ns1`.  Nothing was changed about the `NodePort` definition.  This made me question whether the `NodePort` was even necessary for the `kind: Pod` definition, but when I remove it, I can no longer connect to the node in `ns0` from a pod in `ns1`.

This behavior seems to be consistent across different k8s platforms.  Can someone help me understand what is going on?  I think I might be confused about how k8s DNS is supposed to work.  I just need single stable (not load balanced) DNS name per mongo node in each namespace that is reachable from other namespaces.  Why would the way the pod is defined change whether a pod is addressable from another namespace?  Are the pod names created by a `kind: StatefulSet` somehow different from those created by a `kind: Pod` in terms of DNS?

### Working example of DNS differences

Starting with two empty kubernetes namespaces ns0 and ns1, we can create two Persistent Volume Claims (PVCs).  I don't think this relates to DNS but I have had trouble getting mongo to run in an k8s environment without it, so I am including this for completeness:

#### volume.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongodb-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Once this PVC has been created in both namespaces, we can deploy mongo.  Here are the pod definitions for `ns0` (A) and `ns1` (B).  These should be identical aside from the port numbers (`30000` and `30001` respectively) and the namespace reference in the bind parameter.

#### mongo-a.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    name: mongo
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: mongo
    port: 30000
    targetPort: 30000
    nodePort: 30000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  hostname: mongo
  subdomain: mongo
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
  volumes:
    - name: mongodb-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: mongodb-data
  containers:
    - name: mongo
      image: mongo:latest
      command:
        - mongod
        - "--port"
        - "30000"
        - "--replSet"
        - rs
        - "--bind_ip"
        - "localhost,mongo.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local"
      volumeMounts:
        - name: mongodb-data
          mountPath: /data/db
      ports:
        - containerPort: 30000
```

While in `ns0`, we can create/apply this definition.

Once created, we can exec into the mongo pod.  To verify it is running using its DNS host name:

`mongosh mongodb://mongo.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local:30000`

Now, switching to ns1 (`kubectl config use-context ns1`) we can apply/create the second mongo node.

#### mongo-b.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    name: mongo
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: mongo
    port: 30001
    targetPort: 30001
    nodePort: 30001
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  hostname: mongo
  subdomain: mongo
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
  volumes:
    - name: mongodb-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: mongodb-data
  containers:
    - name: mongo
      image: mongo:latest
      command:
        - mongod
        - "--port"
        - "30001"
        - "--replSet"
        - rs
        - "--bind_ip"
        - "localhost,mongo.mongo.ns1.svc.cluster.local"
      volumeMounts:
        - name: mongodb-data
          mountPath: /data/db
      ports:
        - containerPort: 30001
```

Now we can exec into the second node and confirm using:

`mongosh mongodb://mongo.mongo.ns1.svc.cluster.local:30001`

Now that we have confirmed both sides are running.  We can connect from one to the other.  Exit mongosh on the `mongo-b` node (`ns1`) and connect to the other node in `ns0` using:

`mongosh mongodb://mongo.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local:30000`

This should connect successfully.  From the `mongo-a` pod in ns0, you can likewise connect to the mongo-b node.

However, when I convert the pod definition to a stateful set:

#### mongo-a.stateful.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    name: mongo
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: mongo
    port: 30000
    targetPort: 30000
    nodePort: 30000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      hostname: mongo
      subdomain: mongo
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      volumes:
        - name: mongodb-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mongodb-data
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:latest
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--port"
            - "30000"
            - "--replSet"
            - rs
            - "--bind_ip"
            - "localhost,mongo-0.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongodb-data
              mountPath: /data/db
          ports:
            - containerPort: 30000
```

I can connect exec into the ns0 `mongo-0` pod and connect to the local node using:

`mongosh mongodb://mongo-0.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local:30000`

However, from a mongo node running in `ns1`, that command fails with: `MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo-0.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local`

So, to re-cap: when defined as 'raw' pods, both:

```
mongo.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local:30000
mongo.mongo.ns1.svc.cluster.local:30001
```

Are resolvable from either namespace. But when defined as statefulsets:

```
mongo-0.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local:30000
mongo-0.mongo.ns1.svc.cluster.local:30001
```

Can only be resolved within the corresponding namespace.

I'd like to understand why.  I've tried messing around with service definitions but I'm mostly just flailing and nothing I've tried has worked to make these resolvable from the other namespace.

Comment: To whomever voted to close: if you don't think this question is about a software tool primarily used by programmers, you are on the wrong site.  At the very least, you shouldn't be voting to close questions.

Comment: Why do you need the DNS name for the pod? Typically you would interact with the *service* (`mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local` and `mongo.ns1.svc.cluster.local`). You could be using a Deployment here instead of StatefulSet, unless you actually are creating multiple replicas each with their own stateful storage.

Comment: @larsks For multiple mongo-nodes to work together as a replica set, there needs to be a list of stable hostname or IP when the replica set is initialized.  In addition, those nodes must be informed of its hostname in that set at startup.  And yes, they do need stateful storage.  I'd prefer not to focus on how mongo works, though.  I'm trying to get information on DNS.  Why would the stateful set names not be addressable at the cluster level?   Is there a way to make them so?

Answer (score 1):

In order for Pods in a StatefulSet to have the stable DNS names you're looking for, the service [must be headless](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id):

> A StatefulSet can use a Headless Service to control the domain of its Pods. The domain managed by this Service takes the form: $(service name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local, where "cluster.local" is the cluster domain. As each Pod is created, it gets a matching DNS subdomain, taking the form: $(podname).$(governing service domain), where the governing service is defined by the serviceName field on the StatefulSet.

A [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) is one in which the `clusterIP` is explicitly `None`. This means you *cannot* use a `NodePort` service for this purpose (because a `NodePort` service must have a non-`None` `clusterIP`).

So for those to work the way you want, you would need something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ns0
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
  name: mongo
  namespace: ns0
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: mongo
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    name: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
  name: mongo
  namespace: ns0
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: mongo
  serviceName: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          value: root
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: example
        image: docker.io/mongo:7
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          name: mongo
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo
      name: mongo-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

And similarly for namespace `ns1`. With this in place, from another pod running in `ns0`, we can look up the `mongo` pods in the current namespace:

```
/ # host mongo-0.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local
mongo-0.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local has address 10.244.0.42
/ # host mongo-1.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local
mongo-1.mongo.ns0.svc.cluster.local has address 10.244.0.46
```

And in other namespaces:

```
/ # host mongo-0.mongo.ns1.svc.cluster.local
mongo-0.mongo.ns1.svc.cluster.local has address 10.244.0.43
/ # host mongo-1.mongo.ns1.svc.cluster.local
mongo-1.mongo.ns1.svc.cluster.local has address 10.244.0.47
```

---

If you *also* want to expose your service using a `NodePort`, you could create a second Service resource, e.g:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
  name: mongo-nodeport
  namespace: ns0
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: mongo
    targetPort: 27017
    port: 27017

    # Must be in range 30000-32767
    nodePort: 30017
  selector:
    name: mongo
```

> can you help me understand or point me to a reference for why a directly created pod gets a cluster-level DNS name but those created by a StatefulSet do not?

I don't believe that Pods get a cluster-level DNS name by default. If I deploy these resources:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
  name: mongo-svc
  namespace: ns0
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mongo
    nodePort: 30017
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    name: mongo
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
  name: mongo-pod
  namespace: ns0
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
      value: root
    - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: example
    image: docker.io/mongo:7
    name: mongo
    ports:
    - containerPort: 27017
      name: mongo
```

Then we see:

```
/ # host mongo-pod
Host mongo-pod not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
/ # host mongo-svc
mongo-svc.ns0.svc.cluster.local has address 10.96.40.154
```

A DNS name is only allocated for the service, not for the pod. A pod is able to resolve its own name via `/etc/hosts`, so from within the `mongo-pod` pod, this will work:

```
root@mongo-pod:/# ping -c1 mongo-pod
PING mongo-pod (10.244.0.89): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.244.0.89: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
--- mongo-pod ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.018/0.018/0.018/0.000 ms
```

But that won't work elsewhere, even from other pods in the same namespace, where we would see something like:

```
/ # ping mongo-pod
ping: bad address 'mongo-pod'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I'm digesting it and trying it out. On a side note, can you help me understand or point me to a reference for why a directly created pod gets a cluster-level DNS name but those created by a StatefulSet do not?  I'm trying to get a better understanding of the ins-and-outs.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address the questions in your comment.

Comment: Lots of information to parse.  I probably should be more specific.  When I start a mongo pod in each namespace, I can connect to one from the other.  That is, I exec into the one in ns0 and I can connect mongosh to the one in ns1 from that ns0 pod.  That no longer works with the stateful set even if I change the service name to 'mongo-0' or use 'mongo' the connection uri etc.  I'm not sure if I stumbled on to some quirky behavior or if this is intended.

Comment: I think to address that question I would need to see a complete reproducer (i.e, something I could `kubectl apply`) to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: I've got a hot grill to attend to but I promise to follow up next week with a working example.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I put together working example for cross-namespace pod DNS.  Thanks again for your help.